# How to let users clear their posts cache with WP Super Cache?

Tags: cache, plugin-wp-supercache

Right now with WP Super Cache, when an admin updates a post, the cache is cleared and new cached version is generated. How do I let users do the same with own posts? (When they update their posts the cache gets cleared).

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used this plugin, you had to flush the entire cache to do this:

```
add_action('save_post','custom_clear_wp_super_cache');

function custom_clear_wp_super_cache($post_id) {
    if (function_exists('wp_cache_clear_cache')) {wp_cache_clear_cache();}
}
```

There may (or may not) be a method of flushing the cache for a particular post now.